# SearchController on Navigation Bar is invisible on iOS11

Tags: ios, objective-c

Until iOS 11 was released, I had a search bar added to a UITableViewController. It is hidden under a navigation bar and is visible when user scrolls the table up. On iOS11, adjusting contentOffset or tableview.bound won't hide the search bar properly, sometimes it does work and sometimes it hides the first row, too. So, I've decided to move the search bar to the navigation bar. But, for some reason, I don't see it anywhere. Here's my code at viewDidLoad

```
YearTableViewController.m

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

[super viewDidLoad];


if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {

//iOS11 -> on navigation bar
self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
self.searchController.delegate = self;
self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
self.searchController.searchBar.barStyle = UISearchBarStyleDefault;
self.searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;
[self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = YES;
[self.navigationItem setSearchController:self.searchController];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setPrefersLargeTitles:NO];
[self.navigationItem setLargeTitleDisplayMode:UINavigationItemLargeTitleDisplayModeNever];
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;


} else {

//iOS10 or previous -> on table view
UITableViewController *tableViewControllerForSearch = [[UITableViewController alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
tableViewControllerForSearch.tableView.dataSource = self;
tableViewControllerForSearch.tableView.delegate = self;
tableViewControllerForSearch.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 40;
tableViewControllerForSearch.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:tableViewControllerForSearch];
self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
self.searchController.delegate = self;
self.searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.x, self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.y, self.searchController.searchBar.frame.size.width, 44.0);
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
// No border between cells
tableViewControllerForSearch.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

}
```

**EDITED: 2017/10/20**
As suggested, I've renamed and simplified the structure.

I have the following structure on storyboard.
UINavigationController: Initial view controller
YearPageViewController: Inside, it has YearTableViewController

On iOS10, it works fine. On iOS 11, I don't see the searchBar.
Thanks for your input.

Comment: Why are you setting it on the parentViewController?

Comment: Also naming your UITableViewController "searchController" is confusing

Comment: If I did [self.navigationItem setSearchController:self.searchController], I won't see the search bar.

Comment: Did you find the solution? @yoshitech

Answer (score 0):

What about adding

```
    self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = NO;
```

Obviously the search bar is hidden by default and only is to be seen when scrolling.

Comment: I will try this in my future updates, but so far it's not working. I can create a sample app with the similar structures (view controller stacks), and I suspect having UIPageViewController as a parent of UITableViewController is causing the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hope will helpful to you On iOS11

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
     self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = NO; 
}
```

I known why your view controller is stacks. set '**NO'** flag in **dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation**

```
self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
```

Comment: I will try this in my future updates, but so far it's not working. I can create a sample app with the similar structures (view controller stacks), and I suspect having UIPageViewController as a parent of UITableViewController is causing the issue. Thanks.

Comment: change this flag on your code it's work fine self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;